# Generic method with an argument of two possible types sharing common methods

Tags: c#, string, generics

I write a generic method that will be used either with `String` or `StringBuilder` arguments. It returns the position of the second word in the argument (words can be separated with spaces and line breaks). For using `[]` and `Length()` of the argument, I couldn't invent anything better than the ugly code below. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

```
int PositionOfTheSecondWord<T>(T text) // T can be String or StringBuilder
{
    int pos = 0;
    int state = 0;
    char c;

    // Get length of the text
    // UGLY!
    int length = text is StringBuilder ? (text as StringBuilder).Length : (text as String).Length;

    while (pos <= length - 1)
    {
        // Get the next character
        // UGLY!
        c = text is StringBuilder ? (text as StringBuilder)[pos] : (text as String)[pos];

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') // space
        {
            if (state == 1)
                state = 2; // 2 means the space between the first and the second word has begun
        }
        else // a letter
            if (state == 0)
                state = 1; // 1 means the first word has begun
            if (state == 2)
                return pos;

        pos++;

    }

    return -1;

}
```

P. S. I can't just write a function for String argument and call it from StringBuilder.ToString(), because my StringBuilder can be huge.

Comment: Seems to me it would make more sense to just make an overload, doesnt seem like a case for generics

Comment: This was just an example method for a simple task. What if I had to implement a much more complicated task working with String and StringBuilder, say, several screens long? You suggest copypasting it two times? That's even uglier.

Comment: @Inego: Check out my polymorphism-based answer; it avoids code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the length of your method, this may be a situation for polymorphism:

As noted in other answers, `string` and `StringBuilder` are not related to each other. Therefore, your only chance to use the same method on them is to create wrappers for these two types which are related.

You could define a wrapper base class with your method like this:

```
public abstract class ScannableStringBase
{
    public abstract int Length { get; }

    public abstract char this[int index] { get; }

    public int PositionOfTheSecondWord()
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int state = 0;
        char c;

        int length = this.Length;

        while (pos <= length - 1)
        {
            c = this[pos];

            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') // space
            {
                if (state == 1)
                    state = 2; // 2 means the space between the first and the second word has begun
            }
            else // a letter
                if (state == 0)
                    state = 1; // 1 means the first word has begun
                if (state == 2)
                    return pos;

            pos++;
        }

        return -1;

    }
}
```

From that class, derive subclasses that handle the desired value types:

```
public class ScannableString : ScannableStringBase
{
    public ScannableString(string value)
    {
        this.stringValue = value;
    }

    private readonly string stringValue;

    public override int Length {
        get {
            return stringValue.Length;
        }
    }

    public override char this[int index] {
        get {
            return stringValue[index];
        }
    }
}

public class ScannableStringBuilder : ScannableStringBase
{
    public ScannableString(stringBuilder value)
    {
        this.stringBuilder = value;
    }

    private readonly string stringBuilder;

    public override int Length {
        get {
            return stringBuilder.Length;
        }
    }

    public override char this[int index] {
        get {
            return stringBuilder[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing, you get:

- No code duplication, because `PositionOfTheSecondWord()` is only defined once, in the base class.
- Type-safety, because your `PositionOfTheSecondWord()` method cannot be called on anything other than `string` or `StringBuilder`.
- Extensibility, because if you ever discover you want to support a third type, you can simply derive yet another class from `ScannableStringBase`.

One possible drawback may be that you have to distinguish between the type to analyze somewhere beforehand, so you can decide whether to instantiate a `ScannableString` or a `ScannableStringBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! It is certainly a solution. It is sad though C# doesn't provide simpler means for the task.

Comment: @Inego: Indeed, sometimes I too wish for implicit interfaces and according generic constraints.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best approach would be to use overloaded methods. E.g.:

```
int PostionOfTheSecondWord(string text)
{
    // Code optimized for strings.
}

int PostionOfTheSecondWord(StringBuilder text)
{
    // Code optimized for StringBuilder.
}
```

This will make your code much easier to read and much easier to maintain, and it will perform much better.

Hope this will help you in your quest.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I thought about this from the beginning, but isn't that ugly? Having two duplicate methods different only in the type of the argument? Isn't generics intended to make things simpler?

Comment: Well, its the solution that will work all the time.  Your suggestion will fail if you try PositionOfTheSecondWord(100) - It will compile fine but it will raise a null reference exception at runtime.  There is no constraints on the T-type that will work for both string and StringBuilder and nothing else.

Comment: Generics only make sense if you don't have to worry about the actual actual type of the objects (for example, they'll always implement the same interface, or they'll always derive from the same base class). In your case, as you handle Strings and StringBuilders, which are totally unrelated classes, it's best to handle them in different methods.

Comment: It really seems C# can't offer me anything better than just overloading the method. How sad.

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetPos(string text)
    {
        int length = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (GetChar(text, i) == ' ')
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    int GetPos(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        int length = sb.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (GetChar(sb, i) == ' ')
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    char GetChar<T>(T text, int pos)
    {
        if (text.GetType() == typeof(StringBuilder))
        {
            return (text as StringBuilder)[pos];
        }
        else if (text.GetType() == typeof(String))
        {
            return (text as String)[pos];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong parameter, T must be string or StringBuilder");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is more elegant than my ugly code :) I see usage of overload and run-time checking of types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a generic method, you can use this simpliest code with the same effect.

```
// T can be String or StringBuilder:
static int PositionOfTheSecondWordNew<T>(T text) 
{
    int pos = -1;
    string[] word;

    // If T is string or StringBuilder this line is not necessary:
    if ((text is StringBuilder) || (text is string)) 
    {
        word = text.ToString().Split(new char[]{' ', '\n'});
        pos = word[0].Length;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you didn't notice my "P.S." below the code, which says I can't afford copying huge StringBuilders to strings.